# Loading a custom module in Apache2.4 (undefined symbol error)

Tags: c, apache2

I'm trying to load a custom library in order to use it in Apache2. I did a module.c file that include headers for external .c files that I wrote. I read that I have to use apxs to compile it and `sudo apxs -i -a -c -I /usr/include/ImageMagick/ -I ~/..../libwurfl-master/ -n iiw_module iiw_module.c`

I assume that you know `ImageMagick` (I use `MagickWand` to be precise). `libwurfl` is a git project for parsing `wurfl.xml` file, I configured and installed it.

apxs doesn't return any error (or it seems at least), but when I try to do a `sudo service apache2 restart` I receive this:

```
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error      on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/iiw_module.load: Cannot load   /usr/lib/apache2/modules/iiw_module.so into server:   /usr/lib/apache2/modules/iiw_module.so: undefined symbol: wurfl_interrogation
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

`wurfl_interrogation` is a function inside the `parsing.c` file. `module.c` has `#include "parsing.h"` and the same `parsing.c` has `#include "parsing.h"`

Where is the problem?
Thank you very much in advance!

EDIT1: I have resolved the first issue, but now I have another one:

```
undefined symbol: MagickSetImageCompressionQuality
```

`MagickSetImageCompressionQuality` is a function of the MagickWand library. How can I load the entire library in Apache?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: I think that the problem is pretty clear... How can I resolve the apache error in order to load correctly the costum module?

Comment: Have you tried [LoadFile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_so.html#LoadFile) directive to load the libwurfl so?

Comment: I read that those strings has to be write in httpd.conf that doesn't exist anymore. Do I have to write this line in apache2.conf?

Comment: The line must be before the line where you load your custom module with LoadModule. `LoadFile /path/to/libwurfl.so`

Comment: But I do not have a libwurfl.so module... It doesn't find the wurfl_interrogation function which is in 'parsing.c' (I'll try anyway :D)

Comment: If it is not libwurfl.so, the path must be to the shared object in which wurfl_interrogation function resides in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88877/discussion-between-thenoblesix-and-4566976).